# Why does this system of equations have no solutions? Exercise forbids trying to solve it

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following three equations:

$$ x-y+2z=3$$ $$2x+3y-z=1$$ $$4x+y+3z=-6$$

The specific question is asking me why this system of equations has no solution, it is specifically stated that i cant try to solve it to do this.

Comment: You have to be careful with specific restrictions. You have to be allowed to do *something* in order to solve it. You can see this from the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution then $$2(x-y+2z)+(2x+3y-z)-(4x+y+3x)=3+1-(-6)$$ or
$$0=10,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: For coding theory, the field $\mathbb{F}_5$ would make sense, or $\mathbb{F}_2$. This would not be a contradiction, then.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Also, we have no a contradiction above $\mathbb F_{125}$. or $\mathbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Prove that the rank of the coefficients matrix of the system is 2, but the rank of the augmented matrix is 3, and use Rouché-Capelli theorem.

Comment: In English this is known as the [Rouché-Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem).

Comment: Good to know :)